# Django save file without using form, just by using ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

How can i save file in database without using forms.

**models.py**

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
     myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='folder/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**ajax and html**

```
<input id="id_video" type="file">
<button onclick="upload_video()">save</button>

function upload_video(){

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#id_video')[0].files[0]);

    console.log(formData)

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', url : '/upload-video/',
        async: true,
        data:formData,,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success : function(data){
            alert(data)
        }
    })
}
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_videos(request):

    video_file = request.GET.get('formData')
    # how to save
    video_file.save()
    return Httpresponse('saved')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GET` method can't transport any content data, so you need to use `POST` method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
}
```

Now, inside your `view` you can get the file-like object from `request.FILES` :

```
def upload_videos(request):
    video_file = request.FILES['file']

    # Create model record
    _ = mymodel.objects.create(myfile=video_file.getvalue()) 

    return Httpresponse('saved')
```

OTOH, if you receive the `data` as `POST` param, you can use `io.BytesIO` to get a file-like object, and use it to create model record:

```
import io

def upload_videos(request):
    try:
        video_file = request.FILES['file']
    except KeyError:
        # You can catch KeyError here as well
        # and return a response with 400 status code
        try:
            video_file_data = request.POST['data']
        except KeyError:
            return Httpresponse('No file content', status=400)

        video_file = io.BytesIO(video_file_data)

        # Create model record
        _ = mymodel.objects.create(myfile=video_file.getvalue())
    else:             
        # Create model record
        _ = mymodel.objects.create(myfile=video_file.getvalue()) 

    return Httpresponse('saved')
```

FWIW, you should name your model classes as *CamelCase*.

The above is a basic idea of how to do this, you can enhance the idea to meet your need.

Comment: **video_file_data** is getting None @heemayl

Comment: @c.grey Use the param that you've used for file content in AJAX instead of `data` (if unsure, check `request.POST`).

Comment: request.POST output >> <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: @c.grey Then you need to look at your AJAX so that it sends the correct params and data.

Comment: it prints >> <MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: requirement.txt (text/plain)>]}>

Comment: @c.grey Then you can get the file using `video_file = request.FILES.get('file')` and save directly by `mymodel.objects.create(myfile=video_file)`.